# How to find a DFA for combinations of even and odd occurrences $0,1$?

Tags: proof-explanation, equivalence-relations, formal-languages, automata

> Let $L$ be a language over $\{0,1\}$ whose Nerode equivalence classes are:
>   $$
> \{w|\#_0(w)\mod2=0\quad\land\quad \#_1(w)\mod2=0\}\\
> \{w|\#_0(w)\mod2=0\quad\land\quad \#_1(w)\mod2=1\}\\
> \{w|\#_0(w)\mod2=1\quad\land\quad \#_1(w)\mod2=1\}\\
> \{w|\#_0(w)\mod2=1\quad\land\quad \#_1(w)\mod2=0\}
> $$
>   ($\#_0(w)\mod2=0$ means that the number of zeroes in word $w$ is even).
>
> Also $\epsilon \in L, 0,1,1110\notin L$. Find DFA for the language.

First because there's a finite number of eq. classes by Nerode theorem we know that $L$ is regular so DFA exists for the language.

The solution to the problem is:

[image]

But I don't understand how the DFA accommodates all possible words in $L$.

1) For example what about $111$? It had even number of $0$'s and uneven number of $1$'s so it belongs to the second eq.class. But I don't see how we can arrive to this word using the DFA above.

2) What about the word $00011$? It belongs to the fourth equivalence class but I don't see how to arrive at this word using the DFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every equivalence class belongs to the language, otherwise the language would always be $\Sigma^*$. Since $\varepsilon \in L$ and $0,1,1110 \notin L$, we know that $L$ equals the first equivalence class. Therefore your examples are not counterexamples.